# How to view merge conflict resolution window in GitUp (not github)

Tags: merge-conflict-resolution

In GitUp, while merging changes from one branch into another branch (with conflicts), the UI just shows that there are merge conflicts in an alert message. Is there a way to view the conflicts?

Tried all the screens, conflicts are not shown anywhere.